# How do I insert a string of chars into the middle of a char* and shift all the chararcters to the right without anything being removed

Tags: c

Lets say I have char *p and p has the phrase "this is not easy." and it is null terminated at the end. I want to search through p and where ever I run into 's', I want to put instead "101" without deleting any other characters. So for this example, p goes from "this is not easy." to "thi101 i101 not ea101y." I also can only use the headers stdio.h, stdlib.h, and string.h.

```
char q[] = "s";
char r[] = "101";
    for(int j = 0; s[j]!='\0'; j++){
        if(s[j]==q[0]){
            int temp = 0;
            s[j] = r[temp];
            temp++;
            int temp2 = j;
            while(temp<3){
                for(int k = length; k>j+1; k--){
                    s[k]=s[k-1];

                }
                s[j] = r[temp];
                temp++;
                j++;                    
            }
            j = temp2;
        }
    }
}
```

s is the string I mentioned earlier "this is not easy.".

The output I am current getting is "thi011 i011 not �ea" which cannot be correct.

Comment: **Let say** I ask you what you tried ? And if there's no response in next 2 mins, _I also can_ vote to close this.

Comment: At least the title was reasonably formed as a question (albeit a bit long), which is more than most one-rep questions posted here. The rest, however... ugh.

Comment: I added a snippet of my code and what output I am getting as of now.

Answer (score 1):

First determine the length of "s" (1) and "101" (3). Then, shift all the characters after every occurrence of "s" by 3-1=2, and put the "101".

Of course you must make sure the string buffer is large enough for the operation.